# How to quickly (easy to script) preview 3D vectors / lines?

Tags: .net, python, 3d, ironpython

I am busy reading 3D building models from a tool and thus generating a bunch of `Line(p1, p2)` objects, each consisting of two `Point(x, y, z)` objects. I would like to display these things in a simple 3D viewer, kind of like SVG (which, as I understand, only supports 2D).

The reading is done in Python, specifically IronPython. I could use either a .NET viewer library or write out a text/xml/whatnot file with the data to be displayed by manually opening the result in the appropriate program.

What format / tool would you use to view the data?

(At the moment, this is only for debugging purposes, so it doesn't have to be top-notch. Just a wire-frame will do!)

I did check the mathplot library, but that seems to only plot functions...

**EDIT:** I eventually did go the X3D route and wrote a [little blog post on how to do it](http://darenatwork.blogspot.com/2010/02/how-to-create-3d-wireframe-with-x3d.html). Here is a sample X3D wireframe file for a 1x1x1 cube:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE X3D PUBLIC "ISO//Web3D//DTD X3D 3.0//EN"
  "http://www.web3d.org/specifications/x3d-3.0.dtd">
<X3D profile="Immersive" >
  <Scene>

    <Transform>
      <Shape>
        <LineSet vertexCount="5">
            <Coordinate point="1 0 0
                               1 1 0
                               0 1 0
                               0 0 0
                               1 0 0"
                               />
        </LineSet>
    </Shape>
    <Shape>
        <LineSet vertexCount="5">
            <Coordinate point="1 0 1
                               1 1 1
                               0 1 1
                               0 0 1
                               1 0 1"
                               />
        </LineSet>
    </Shape>
    <Shape>
        <LineSet vertexCount="5">
            <Coordinate point="0 0 1
                               1 0 1
                               1 0 0
                               0 0 0
                               0 0 1"
                               />
        </LineSet>
    </Shape>
    <Shape>
        <LineSet vertexCount="5">
            <Coordinate point="0 1 1
                               1 1 1
                               1 1 0
                               0 1 0
                               0 1 1"
                               />
        </LineSet>
      </Shape>
    </Transform>
  </Scene>
</X3D>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using the writing to file approach you could investigate [X3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X3D), which is the successor to VRML. Also see [this list of vector graphics markup languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vector_graphics_markup_languages)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a 3D-programming expert but there is a simple trick you can do.
If you *imagine* that the `z` axis is vertical to your screen then you can project a 3D point `(x, y, z)` like this: `(zoom_factor*(x/z), zoom_factor*(y/z))`

Comment: thanks, I might have to resort to something like that.
I was hoping for a ready made viewer that will take my 3D points, though. Also, using your technique I will have to do some transformations (should be easy) as z-axis actually goes up (elevation) and the x/y plane is normal to the screen...

Answer (score 1):

You might try the [PyQwt3D](http://pyqwt.sourceforge.net/) package.  If that doesn't work, here's a [list of other python packages](http://www.vrplumber.com/py3d.py) that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could look at POV-Ray. It's a ray tracer that has its own text based scene description language. IIRC, there is a python module which will generate the scene files, if not, it wouldn't be difficult to do by hand. Displaying line segments at low resolution should render fairly quickly.

Check here: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/205451/

Also, python is the scripting language for Blender.